# Parsing json in node.js server with jquery gives 404 error

Tags: jquery, node.js, json

I am using node.js and socket.io to build a simple web app, It is the very first time I use such technology.

I have a server file emitting events and a client file responding plus I have a file called roomParser.js that is meant to parse a JSON file in the same folder and initialize the available rooms. the file looks like this

```
    let select= document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];

$.getJSON('rooms.json', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
select.innerHTML="";

/*
for(let i=0; i<rooms.length; i++){
    select.innerHTML+="<options value="+rooms[i]+">"+rooms[i]+"</options>";
}*/
```

Even if the rooms.json file is in the same folder as my roomParser.js I still get a 404 error that tells me the file hasn't been found.

Also here are my client and server files if they can be somehow useful

**SERVER**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var userlist= new Array();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});



io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('user connected')
    socket.on('connection tried', function (name) {
        if(!find(name)){
            userlist.push(name);
            socket.broadcast.emit('connection message', name + "has connected");
            console.log(name);
        }
        else
            socket.emit('RegistrationErr','username');

    })
});

function find(name){
    for( let i=0; i<userlist.length; i++){
        if(userlist[i]==name)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

server.listen(3000);
```

**CLIENT**

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io()


    $('#formElem').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        socket.emit('connection tried', $('#name').val());
        return false;
    })

    socket.on('RegistrationErr', function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })




});
```

Comment: try using importing json file in your roomParser.js like const jsonData = require('./rooms.json');

Answer (score 0):

You should read the file using 'fs' first and assign the JSON data to a variable and then proceed with it, see: 
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback